# AngularJS: Submit button requires two clicks to work

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a submit button on my form but for some weird reason it requires me to click on the button twice before it calls the save function underneth, I am using Pug for my HTML

Here is my HTML template:

```
<form ng-submit="save()">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-md-6">
        <ol ng-model="service.category" title="Select a category" class="nya-bs-select">
          <li nya-bs-option="category in categories.rows" class="nya-bs-option"><a> <span>{{category.name}} </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-md-6">
        <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">Service Name</span>
          <input type="text" ng-model="service.name" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-md-6">
        <textarea ng-model="service.description" placeholder="Service Description" rows="10" class="form-control"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-md-6">
        <button type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default"> Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

The save function called is as

```
angular.module('App.controllers')
.controller('UpdateServiceCtrl', [
  '$scope', '$state', 'ServicesService', 'Notification',
function ($scope, $state, ServicesService, Notification) {
  $scope.service = $scope.$parent.service;
  $scope.categories = $scope.$parent.categories;

   /**
   * Edits a service
   * @param  {integer} serviceID Id of the service to be edited
   * @return {undefined}           Does not return any values
   */

  $scope.save = function () {
    $scope.service.category_id = $scope.service.category.id;
    ServicesService.save($scope.service, $scope.service.id)
    .then(function (result) {
      $state.reload();
    })
  }
}]);
```

Comment: how do you know that it's not executing the first time and you just aren't seeing a result right away because of the async save operation?

Comment: put a console.log at the start of your `$scope.save` function. does it log it correctly? If yes there's probably something wrong with your service.

Comment: I monitor the XMLHTTPRequest log, so I know. @Claies

Comment: @lexith I did,  it does not get called

Comment: and on the second click it's called twice? could you remove the `ng-submit="save()"` at the top of your form and just place a click handler on your button and try again?

Comment: @lexith No, it is called once, gonna take out that part,  reason why it called twice was because I got frustrated and clicked multiple times

Comment: @lexith Just tried with `ng-click="save()"` and it is called immediately, but not with `ng-submit`

Comment: can't find something in your markup. That's exactly the code you're using right now, yes? definitely `<button type="submit"></button>`? Could you try input instead of the button? Actually im just throwing guesses around right now, can't really help you. It's weird that it does work on the second click though.

Comment: @lexith I actually used `input` before changing it to `button`

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the submit button after it clicked first time using
`ng-disabled='isButtonEnabled'` your html.
 Modify your save like this

```
$scope.save = function () {
$scope.isButtonEnabled = false; 
    $scope.service.category_id = $scope.service.category.id;
    ServicesService.save($scope.service, $scope.service.id)
    .then(function (result) {
      $state.reload();
    })
  }
```

Let me know if it doesn't works.

Comment: I am not sure that is my problem

Comment: Reaon why this won't work is because no matter how long I wait it still does not get called

Comment: hi @JamesOkpeGeorge i have create a plunkr of your code.  check this out  http://plnkr.co/edit/OzF4PFJQygw5qvgeQAXH?p=preview  It looks like it is functioning well here.